# Mariadb 1000% CPU

Tags: linux, nginx, mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a big problem with my site (Laravel based), I have from 1000 to 1500 contemporary visitors, and I have a problem with mariadb, practically when people use filters, and other options that require the use of mysql, the server cpu reaches 1000%, following my configurations:

Mysql:

```
    [client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysql]
max_allowed_packet = 128M

[mysqld]
ignore_db_dirs=cmsetiofiotest
local-infile=0
ignore_db_dirs=lost+found
character-set-server=utf8
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

bind-address=0.0.0.0
# optimized my.cnf for MariaDB 5.5.x
# by eva2000
# vbtechsupport.com

tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp

innodb=ON
#skip-federated
##skip-pbxt
##skip-pbxt_statistics
#skip-archive
#skip-name-resolve
#old_passwords
back_log = 1024
max_connections = 1500
key_buffer_size = 1024M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1024M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10240M
join_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
table_definition_cache = 8192
table_open_cache = 8192
thread_cache_size = 384
wait_timeout = 1800
connect_timeout = 10
tmp_table_size = 1536M
max_heap_table_size = 1536M
max_allowed_packet = 128M
#max_seeks_for_key = 4294967295
#group_concat_max_len = 1024
max_length_for_sort_data = 1024
net_buffer_length = 16384
max_connect_errors = 100000
concurrent_insert = 2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
# query_cache boost for MariaDB >10.1.2+
# https://community.centminmod.com/posts/30811/
query_cache_limit = 1536K
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2K
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65536
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
default-storage-engine = InnoDB

log_warnings=1
slow_query_log=0
long_query_time=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/slowq.log
#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

# innodb settings
innodb_large_prefix=1
innodb_purge_threads = 4
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 2000
innodb_data_file_path= ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12288M

## https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_instances
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=12

innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
#innodb_thread_concurrency = 32
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa=1

# 200 * # DISKS
innodb_io_capacity = 1600
innodb_io_capacity_max = 3200
innodb_read_io_threads = 7
innodb_write_io_threads = 7
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0

# mariadb settings
[mariadb]
#thread-handling = pool-of-threads
#thread-pool-size= 20
#mysql --port=3307 --protocol=tcp
#extra-port=3307
#extra-max-connections=1

userstat = 0
key_cache_segments = 1
aria_group_commit = none
aria_group_commit_interval = 0
aria_log_file_size = 1024M
aria_log_purge_type = immediate 
aria_pagecache_buffer_size = 1024M
aria_sort_buffer_size = 256M

[mariadb-5.5]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1

#ignore_db_dirs=
query_cache_strip_comments=0

innodb_read_ahead = linear
innodb_adaptive_flushing_method = estimate
innodb_flush_neighbor_pages = 1
innodb_stats_update_need_lock = 0
innodb_log_block_size = 512

log_slow_filter =admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk

[mysqld_safe] 
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
#nice = -5
open-files-limit = 8192

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 128M

[myisamchk] 
tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp
key_buffer = 1536M 
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 384M
write_buffer = 384M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mariadb-10.0]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1

# 2 variables needed to switch from XtraDB to InnoDB plugins
#plugin-load=ha_innodb
#ignore_builtin_innodb

## MariaDB 10 only save and restore buffer pool pages
## warm up InnoDB buffer pool on server restarts
#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1
#innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1
innodb_buffer_pool_populate=0
## Disabled settings
performance_schema=OFF
innodb_stats_on_metadata=OFF
innodb_sort_buffer_size=2M
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size=128M
query_cache_strip_comments=0
log_slow_filter =admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk

[mariadb-10.1]
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_default_row_format = dynamic
innodb_file_per_table = 1

## wsrep specific
# wsrep_on=OFF
# wsrep_provider
# wsrep_cluster_address
# binlog_format=ROW
# default_storage_engine=InnoDB
# innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
# innodb_doublewrite=1
# query_cache_size=0

# 2 variables needed to switch from XtraDB to InnoDB plugins
#plugin-load=ha_innodb
#ignore_builtin_innodb

## MariaDB 10 only save and restore buffer pool pages
## warm up InnoDB buffer pool on server restarts
#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=1
#innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=1
innodb_buffer_pool_populate=0
## Disabled settings
performance_schema=OFF
innodb_stats_on_metadata=OFF
innodb_sort_buffer_size=2M
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size=128M
query_cache_strip_comments=0
log_slow_filter =admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk

# Defragmenting unused space on InnoDB tablespace
innodb_defragment=1
innodb_defragment_n_pages=7
innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy=0
innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs=20
innodb_defragment_fill_factor=0.9
innodb_defragment_frequency=40
```

And use of the cpu:

[image: 1000% CPU MYSQL]

My server specifications are: 
14 Dedicated Intel® Xeon® Gold 6140 Cores
64gb of ram
1 gigabit connection

I have optimized what I could with redis, but nothing is served, the load is excessive the same,

thanks and best regards

Comment: @Womble - the poor OP was sent here from StackOverflow, where his question was "Closed > Off-topic".  The OP clearly has a problem, and he's clearly told us everything he can.  Couldn't we at give some additional suggestions as to how he can troubleshoot his/her "100% CPU" situation?  The OP needs some *GUIDANCE* in order to ask a "better question".  IMHO...

Comment: @ZioBomba Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis and actionable suggestions.  View profile, Network profile, please

Comment: @ZioBomba  For your consideration of recent success, look at this URL.
https://www.instagram.com/p/BqicW3Hn_5Y/    Thanks

Comment: @ZioBomba If you could post the information requested a couple of comments up, MINIMUM of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  and  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  I will try to help you get below 1200% CPU.  Merry Christmas

Comment: @zioBomba Suggestions read_buffer_size=256K, read_rnd_buffer_size=192K, query_cache_min_res_unit=512, aria_pagecache_age_threshold=900, key_cache_age_threshold=7200.  If you could Skype with me, we can review why these are important Global Variables compared to your current settings.  CPU will be reduced and delays should be minimized with these values.  Do you have SSD for data storage?

Comment: @ZioBomba A) Have the Dec 26, 18 Suggestions been implemented?  B) What is your perception of the improvement in your server?  C) Do you have SSD for data storage?  D) I see you have 18 cores on your server.  1200% CPU / 18 cores = 66% overall busy.  E) By not posting your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; you are indicating you do NOT want your system analyzed to allow performance suggestions to be made available to enhance your productivity.

Comment: High CPU almost always means (1) lack of good INDEX, or (2) a poorly formulated query.  It if happens again, start a new Question and provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: tmp_table_size = 200M max_heap_table_size = 200M query_cache_size = 50M (or 0)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however the problem was solved, it was a query problem in the database! thanks to all

Comment: @ZioBomba Thanks your update.  For improved performance, try the Dec 26, 2018 suggestions by me.  After 7 days indicate performance better OR worse, please.  Our motto is Make Every Moment Count by reducing WAIT time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clearly you've got a performance problem: all CPUs on your SMP production server are maxed out at 100%.  "Not good" :(
2. Minor quibble: there's no such thing as "1000%". Nevertheless...
3. Before anybody can help, you need to get a better understanding of the root cause:

   - Maybe there's a bug in your app.  Maybe you can tune your database and/or tune your server. Or maybe you just need to buy more hardware.
   - You might consider ["dockerizing"](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2015/10/getting-started-with-laravel-mariadb-mysql-docker/) your infrastructure, so you can "spin up" more instances as needed to handle the load.
4. But the FIRST thing you need to do is to establish a "performance baseline", to better understand WHAT is causing the performance deficit.  We don't even have enough information yet to determine if the problem is in the database, in Laravel/PHP, or "something else".

   These links might help:

   - [Profiling Your Laravel Application With Clockwork](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2017/08/14/profiling-your-laravel-application-with-clockwork/)
   - [Improve MariaDB Performance Using Query Profiling](https://dzone.com/articles/improve-mariadb-performance-using-query-profiling)
   - [12 Tips for Laravel Performance Optimization](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-performance-optimization/)